# iOS 7 app icons showing up black as soon as I add new images

Tags: ios, image, ios7, icons, xcode5

I start writing this app under iOS 6 I managed to fix everything with respect to image and deprecated APIs without issue.

I am creating an new icon to support iOS 7 style but regardless of if I use asset catalog and or straight paths to images as soon as I add a new reference whenever I launch applications I get a black icon being rendered.

I am clearly doing something wrong.

Here is my asset catalog showing all mapped images. They aren't actually showing up in the application, and I have black icons across all iOS applications.

[image]

Whenever I launch I get a black icon. Does it have to do with some setting in Info.plist file?

Here it is.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>en</string>
    <key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
    <string>${PRODUCT_NAME}</string>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>${EXECUTABLE_NAME}</string>
    <key>CFBundleIcons</key>
    <dict/>
    <key>CFBundleIcons~ipad</key>
    <dict/>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>com.neckbeardrepublic.${PRODUCT_NAME:rfc1034identifier}</string>
    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>7.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>${PRODUCT_NAME}</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>APPL</string>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>1.0</string>
    <key>LSRequiresIPhoneOS</key>
    <true/>
    <key>UIAppFonts</key>
    <array>
        <string>Lato-Black.ttf</string>
        <string>FontAwesome.ttf</string>
    </array>
    <key>UIPrerenderedIcon</key>
    <true/>
    <key>UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities</key>
    <array>
        <string>armv7</string>
    </array>
    <key>UIStatusBarHidden</key>
    <false/>
    <key>UIStatusBarHidden~ipad</key>
    <true/>
    <key>UIStatusBarTintParameters</key>
    <dict>
        <key>UINavigationBar</key>
        <dict>
            <key>Style</key>
            <string>UIBarStyleDefault</string>
            <key>Translucent</key>
            <false/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
    <key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key>
    <false/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Extremely frustrating. I have also just tried providing the specific files without much avail either.

Can anyone pinpoint the issue?

Comment: How come they are not showing in your plist file? they should be right under `CFBundleIcons` did you drag & drop them

Comment: @meda I have done both drag and drop as well as placing each on individually.

Comment: Are you dragging png files?

Comment: What formats are the images in, .png, .jpg, .jpeg…?

Comment: @Abizern yes they are pngs.

Comment: @DavidG. images are pngs.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

First, check that the image files you're using for app icons are appropriate.  See [Apple's Human Interface Guidelines on App Icons](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/AppIcons.html) for the full details, but particularly relevant to this question:

> Avoid transparency. An app icon should be opaque. If the icon’s
>   boundaries are smaller than the recommended sizes—or you use
>   transparency to create “see-through” areas—the resulting icon can
>   appear to float on a black background, which tends to look especially
>   unattractive on the beautiful wallpapers that users choose.

If you're using transparency, for example a black image on a transparent background, the icon may appear completely black in iOS.

Next, there are a few ways to tell iOS about the icons for your app.  The new mechanism is to use the Asset Catalog; Apple has a guide on [Migrating an App Icon or Launch Image Set](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-image_catalog-1.0/StoringAppIconsandLaunchImagesinanAssetCatalog/StoringAppIconsandLaunchImagesinanAssetCatalog.html).

The old, simple method is to add the icon filenames to your Info.plist file `CFBundleIcons`.  According to Apple's docs on [App-Related Resources](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/App-RelatedResources/App-RelatedResources.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH6-SW1):

> Regardless of how many different icons your app has, you specify them
>   using the `CFBundleIcons` key in the `Info.plist` file. The value of that
>   key is an array of strings, each of which contains the filename of one
>   of your icons. The filenames can be anything you want, but all image
>   files must be in the PNG format and must reside in the top level of
>   your app bundle. (Avoid using interlaced PNGs.) When the system needs
>   an icon, it choose the image file whose size most closely matches the
>   intended usage.

Comment: @myusuf3 I updated the answer to include a warning against using transparent PNG's ;)